# Regex split string every two characters

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5

I need to process some `QString` that looks like this `" 12 ab, 1a 2ab f 12efa "`, I want to convert it to a `QStringList` like this `("12", "ab", "1a", "2a", "b", "f", "12", "ef", "a")`.

```
QString string("  12 ab, 1a, 2ab f 12efa    ");
QStringList list;
list = string.split(QRegularExpression("[\\s|,]"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

Output:

```
("12", "ab", "1a", "2ab", "f", "12efa")
```

So if the regexp is able to split every two, I can make it just with `QString::split`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to use a different regex, then use a `QRegularExpressionMatchIterator` to add the matches to a `QStringList`.

The `([\\w]{1,2}])` regex will match and capture a pair of consecutive [word characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) or a single word character.

Check out the following code and see if this is what you need.

```
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QRegularExpression>

int main(void)
{
    QString string("  12 ab, 1a, 2ab f 12efa    ");

    QRegularExpression re("([\\w]{1,2})");
    QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = re.globalMatch(string);

    QStringList list;
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
        QString word = match.captured(1);
        list << word;
    }

    qDebug() << list;

    return 0;
}
```